# How to change the files name (results stored as pickle file) automatically in Jenkins for every build ? Read below to know more about the question

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm using python 2.7 and Jenkins latest version.

When Jenkins is triggered, results from python script is stored in pickle files for the future use.

Whenever a build happens, I want to store every build results of a python script in pickle files. I'm able to store the results in pickle files.
How can I save every build's results with different file names so that I can access the files from the python script.

Is it possible to add build_number and job_name as a file name 
or appending/prepending build_number to current file name ?

Later with another python script I should be able to access the current and previous successful build (last 2 successful builds) pickle files to compare the results.

For the solution, Changes in Jenkinsfile or python script or both are welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From a python script you can use [`os.rename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) to rename your file. Jenkins sets environment variables for a running job to give you the job name and number.

Combinig the two you can do:

```
job_name = os.environ.get('JOB_NAME', 'default_name')
build_number = os.environ.get('BUILD_NUMBER', 1)
new_output = "{}_{}.bin".format(job_name, build_number)
os.rename(original_output, new_output)
```

Comment: Thanks @handras, As I'm new here, can you please elaborate ? If possible with an example.

Comment: My answer already has an example, which is a Python code. Have tried runnig it? What part gave you error?

Comment: Hey, @handras, result I wanted is.. job_name and build_number should be appended to pickle file that is generated from the script. Later with another python script I should be able to access the current and previous successful build (last 2 successful builds) pickle files to compare the results. Please help with this.